# K8s ingress redirect from domain without cert to another with cert

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

There is k8s cluster with nginx-ingress. There is domain without certificate (example.io). I want redirect all requests to another my domain with certificate (example.com) without exception about bad certificate on domain example.io in browser. How can I do it? Thanks.

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/permanent-redirect, ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet didn;t help me.
Example:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: redirect-ingress
  annotations:
  ??????
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: some-cluster-service
          servicePort: 2020
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-side-https-enforcement-through-redirect) annotation:

> When using SSL offloading outside of cluster (e.g. AWS ELB) it may be
> useful to enforce a redirect to HTTPS even when there is no TLS
> certificate available. This can be achieved by using the
> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true" annotation in
> the particular resource.